# AutoMapper IEnumerable mapping bug

Tags: c#, entity-framework, automapper

I have a strange thing happening with automapper.

Do someone have a clue why this code is returning a value for the InstitutionsImplantations field :

```
var result1 = new List<DataModel.Implantations>();
foreach (var c in collection)
{
    DataModel.Implantations i = Mapper.Map<DataModel.Implantations>(c);
    result1.Add(i);
}
var item1 = result1.Where(x => x.Nom == "Valdor").FirstOrDefault();
Console.WriteLine(item1.InstitutionsImplantations);
```

While this one (on the same collection), return null for InstitutionsImplantations :

```
var result2 = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<DataModel.Implantations>>(collection);
var item2 = result2.Where(x => x.Nom == "Valdor").FirstOrDefault();
Console.WriteLine(item2.InstitutionsImplantations);
```

Facts : 
The mapping done by autommaper on the IEnumerable is correct for the +/- first 300 items in the list, then after, some item collection have a "badly" mapped InstitutionsImplantations property.

InstitutionsImplantations property is an object "proxy" from a EF result.

do you have an idea why this is happening ?

Tx you !

Comment: Never seen anything like that, but the "normal" way to use AutoMapper would be `collection.Select(c => Mapper.Map<Implantations>(c))` so you don't need the bloated `IEnumerable` mappings. This form is essentially equal to your first snippet. Doesn't answer the question of course. It would be interesting to know if this is a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem, using the automapper source code to see what was going on behind the scenes.

When automapper is processing the IEnumerable collection, its using a caching mechanism to avoid to have to remap an already mapped object that was present in the collection.

You would say, its fair, no reason to have the same object mapped to a different result.

But in my scenario, I forget to add that I was also using an AfterMap delegate at the mapping declaration.

In this AfterMap I was doing this (To avoid circular references problem) :

```
mappedItem.InstitutionsImplantations.Institution.InstitutionsImplantations = null;
```

This problem of this is that, I though that it was only impacting the result of the mapping (AfterMap delegate), and nothing else, but I was wrong it is also impacting the "Cache" being put in place !
This is not was I wanted, because in this case it did also impact all following mapping computing in the collection, using "Null" for the following mapped InstitutionsImplantations object, instead of brand new mapping.

My first solution was clean because the caching mechanism did not work between 2 "different" mapping.
And I didn't find an easy way to disable this collection caching mechanism inside automapper !